Winforms Chart Control change the axislabel font size
How do I change the font size of the axis labels in a Winforms chart control?
I create the chart this way:
chart1.Series.Clear();
        var series = chart1.Series.Add("Difetti");

        foreach (var stat in Stats)
        {
            var pt = series.Points.Add(stat.Count);
            pt.AxisLabel = stat.Nome_TipoDifetto;
            pt.Label = stat.Count.ToString();
        }


I found out I can write:
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font.FontFamily, 14);

